# I want to use selenium automation for automating multiple webpages in one window, I am currently using Pyside-6 qtwebengineview

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, qtwebengine, qtwebview

I want to use selenium automation for automating multiple webpages in one window, I am currently using Pyside-6 qtwebengineview, i couldn't find any webdriver for the same. I am looking to automate typing and pressing of button on a few sites for testing. Since qtwebengineview is based on chromium, i should be good with the chromium webdriver right? But if so, what exact version am i supposed to use for compatibility? Any other solutions to achieve the same actions with a few websites in the same window?
I have researched a bit about this and some individual or a group of individuals has created a unofficial webdriver for the qtwebengineview, but i couldn't figure it out. https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver

Thanks!

P.S. I am brand new to this field, so if any mistakes in my question or ideology, please don't mind!